# How does the existence of a unique geodesic in non-positive curvature follow from Cartan-Hadamard?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Cartan-Hadamard states that a non-positively curved Riemannian manifold is covered by $\mathbb{R}^n$. How does it follow that in each homotopy class of paths from $x$ to $y$ there exists a unique geodesic?

I already know that geodesics minimise lengths locally and that the geodesics given by exp$(tv)$ are globally length minimising. Does it follow that any geodesic is of this form?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: Are you asking about existence or uniqueness of minimizing geodesic? Also, you are missing the completeness assumption (since you did not assume compactness of the manifold). Lastly, just from a diffeomorphism of the universal cover to $R^n$ you cannot make any conclusions about uniqueness of the minimizer. Existence comes from completeness, it has nothing to do with $R^n$.